# how to not allow the textbox text (number only) to start with 0 (zero)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i have an exercise to make something like a calculator. 7 `TextBox`. It should look like

`1/2 + 2/3 = 7/6` where every number is in his own box and the `+` has one too. must fill in the  boxes before "`=`" numbers ( and `+ ; - ; * ; /`  in the one in the middle) and then check with button if there are not some letters or symbols. ok made it, but the teacher ask me to write 013 in the textbox, so.. how to make it like that so if the numbers start with 0 then after clicking the button it give me error. something like: 
if ...... then
msgBox("ERROR")

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Also VBA and VS are totally different. Are you trying to do this in VB.Net by any chance?

Comment: Visual Basic 2010, i actually dont know what vs or vba are, but i though they are closest, not sure. ok what i have made, well the code is in school`s PC. but i made something like
if t2.text = 0 and t4.text = 0 then
msgbox ("0 is not allowed as denominator (not sure if it is right, checked the word in google")
isNumeric (t1.text) = false then
msgbox ("use only numbers")
and did that or all textboxes, btw i rename them to t1 instead of textbox1, for easier work.

Comment: Not able to give a direct answer as it's frowned upon to answer schoolwork. But I think you should look at the **instr** function. Plenty of info on that on the web, but here is one place to look: [http://www.vbtutor.net/vb2010/vb2010_Lesson13.htm](http://www.vbtutor.net/vb2010/vb2010_Lesson13.htm) Best, Rob